# How To Add Field (Newsletter QUEUE)

Tags: newsletter

I need to add a dropdown "Type"

For example:[image]

then

[image]

Question:
How can i add dropdown "TYPE" in QUEUE informartion like the image above and how can save it when i click "Save Newsletter"?

[image]

Question:
How can i send the newsletter to the specific subscriber that has a "Type" like "Customer" if the newsletter template name is "Customer"?

Comment: I have NO idea what you are talking about. What form? Do you want to save it? Please describe (and maybe add screenshots) what you want to do.

Comment: Hi @FabianBlechschmidt i already put screenshots. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the block and add the column to the grid `\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Queue_Grid::_prepareColumns`. I'm not sure whether `newsletter_type` in the table is what you need. If not you have to change `\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Queue_Grid::_prepareCollection` too, to add the columns you want.

And maybe this extension solves your problem with a little bit XML:
https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl